# BIRT log levels and details

Tags: java, logging, log4j, birt

I know that BIRT has the log levels OFF, SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, and FINEST. But is there a doc somewhere to show what events get logged for which level, along with the formatting?

Specifically, I'm trying to see if any of this is logged:

- Properly formatted and accurate timestamp Status code for the event
  type
- Device identifier (MAC address or other unique identifier)
- Session / Transaction ID
- Autonomous System Number
- Source IP (IPv4/IPv6)
- Destination IP (IPv4/IPv6)
- Response time
- Additional headers (i.e., HTTP headers)
- Username and/or ID
- The command executed
- Data formatted as key-value pairs allowing for easy extraction
- A unique event identifier for event correlation, per event

I'm currently using JBoss with the log level set to FINEST.

Comment: Not much related to the question, but you may be looking for an APM instead, like Elastic or Datadog. An APM should provide all of those informations in a queriable way.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your question and the list items you mention seem not related to each other at all.
BIRT does not even know any of these, they are all web server related.
Anyway, there is no documentation of what BIRT logs. BIRT's log messages can be considered as a debugging aid only.

But if you are using a servlet or anything to access BIRT, then it should be possible to use Datadog or something like that to get what you want.